# Get menu item of a node

Tags: 8

I have a node (in D8) which is placed in the menu "Main navigation". How do I get the menu item (in code)? In Drupal 7 you could use `$node->menu` but in 8.x, the object is not populated with menu information. So, how do I retrieve it? I also want to support another type of menus in the future, so something which works with more than the `menu_link_content` module is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;

$node_id = 1;
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$result = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));

dpm($result);
```

Comment: Which will give us an array of all menu items this node belongs to. We can then foreach for the menu name to get the one we need.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Just a note that I added this to get to the actual MenuLinkContent object
 ```/* @var $menuLink Drupal\menu_link_content\Plugin\Menu\MenuLinkContent */
    $menuLink = array_pop($result);``` which gives you an instance of https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link_content%21src%21Entity%21MenuLinkContent.php/class/MenuLinkContent/8.8.x