# if current_node is in menu, do something in theme.inc

Tags: 8, navigation

I'm trying to check if the current node (of a specific content type) has been added to a menu (using the "**Provide a menu link**" in the node edit GUI).

if it has, I need to set a variable in *.theme.inc*, using `THEME_preprocess_page`.

I've been digging through drupal.org docs and found those two questions [find Menu Settings of node, given URL alias (or node ID)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194254/find-menu-settings-of-node-given-url-alias-or-node-id) and [Get menu item of a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197760/get-menu-item-of-a-node) seem relevant but not quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set if the node has menu link you can use [menu_ui_get_menu_link_defaults](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_ui%21menu_ui.module/function/menu_ui_get_menu_link_defaults/8.7.x) function from [menu_ui.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_ui%21menu_ui.module/8.7.x) something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function YOUMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    // Get the default menu link.
    $defaults = menu_ui_get_menu_link_defaults($node);
    if ($defaults['id']) {
      // It has a menu
     // set your variable here.
    }
    else {
      // It has no menu link
      // It mean Provide a menu link not checked
    }
  }
  }
```