# Add theme suggestion to a node depending on the menu it belongs to

Tags: theming, nodes, hooks, navigation

I have a mega menu that displays child menu items when you click on a parent menu item in form of a drop-down menu. The thing is that, this menu, also displays cards as nodes and I want to add a theme suggestion only to this card nodes that are inside the menu drop-down.

I can get the node with a simple `MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_node_alter()` hook but I don't know how to get the menu item of it.

I've tried `menu_ui_get_menu_link_defaults($node)` as seen in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288890/if-current-node-is-in-menu-do-something-in-theme-inc) but it always returns 'main', which is correct but, also almost every node on the page apart from the drop-down menu node seems to come from it and, therefore, that's not what I want.

All I need is an exclusive theme suggestion for this nodes represented on the mega menu drop-down

Comment: Why not just create a new view mode (e.g. menu_card), and render the nodes in that view mode? It'd be cleaner that way plus you get the standard `node__menu_card` suggestion already waiting for you

Comment: Yeah, display the nodes in that menu in a new view mode and you immediately have the template suggestion.

Comment: Agree with the other commenters, new view mode is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new *view mode* just for this types of nodes that are rendered on the menu, is the best approach, specially if this nodes are just from one bundle like 'page'.